# CSS button with slanted bottom right corner

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a rectangle button with a transparent mask over the bottom right, as per this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/c6gUX/

```
body {
background: #fff;
padding: 5em;
}
.button {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'RalewayRegular', Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0.5em 1.2em 0.5em 0.8em;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.button:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFA13E 0px, #E56204 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.button:after {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/8Vvw1Sw.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    bottom: -12px;
    content: " ";
    height: 38px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    width: 36px;
    z-index: 99;
}
.orange-grad {
    background: #ffa13e; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffa13e 0%, #ff7805 100%, #ff7805 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffa13e), color-stop(100%,#ff7805), color-stop(100%,#ff7805)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffa13e 0%,#ff7805 100%,#ff7805 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffa13e 0%,#ff7805 100%,#ff7805 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffa13e 0%,#ff7805 100%,#ff7805 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffa13e 0%,#ff7805 100%,#ff7805 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffa13e', endColorstr='#ff7805',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
```

As you can see, i've achieved it with a quite hacky way. I've untested this cross-browser and suspect IE to mess it up without a shim for :after, etc.

How can I achieve this cross-browser modern? How can I make it work when overlayed onto an image so it's effectively transparent? (See below image)

From PSD:

[image]

My fiddle on an image:

[image]

Logically I know that IE6/7 will need an image and i'm kinda OK with that.

Word length. Sometimes the button doesn't have 'Read more', so need a 100% width solution.

**Edit**

I am thinking of using a Sprite. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKVmm.png)

Comment: If you gonna use a image for the older browsers, why not use the same solution for modern browsers?

Comment: I agree. If you use an image for old browsers do the same for standard ones. Otherwise I'm not sure IE6-7 would like the CSS3 image overlays.

Comment: The words aren't always the same length. I'm glad i'm not the only one that thinks it's hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is tricky - particularly with your combination of a gradient with the beveled corner. The closest I could get is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/wEQD7/), which makes use of CSS gradients to achieve the effect you're after, based on Lea Verou's [awesome article](http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/).

The relevant CSS is:

```
.button {    
    background: #ffa13e; /* fallback */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #ff7805 10px, #ffa13e 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #ff7805 10px, #ffa13e 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #ff7805 10px, #ffa13e 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #ff7805 10px, #ffa13e 100%);
}
```

That's the only way to get the background image to show through (that I know of). The drawback is that the gradient is not your linear one from top to bottom, but at an angle. I don't *think* it's possible to combine multiple gradients to match your visual precisely. But it is pretty close:

[image: Gradient beveled effect]

I'd suggest that this is the perfect candidate for progressive enhancement - older IE will get a solid background colour but that's perfectly acceptable (i.e. I wouldn't personally bother trying for an image fallback).

**Note:** there have been numerous changes between the Working Draft and the Candidate Recommendation for the gradient syntax, one of which is the angle of the gradient:

[image: Gradient degrees syntax change]

From the [IE Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/06/25/unprefixed-css3-gradients-in-ie10.aspx). Hence the unprefixed version requires a different `deg` value.

Comment: Okay, I just learnt so much :) Thanks man, nice answer. +10 kitten points for the body bg.

Comment: No problem - was a fun one to try and figure out. I'll always use a kitten to illustrate a point if I can :)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of it..... I think this will help You.. use it with ur image.. this will solve cross-browser issue...

http://jsfiddle.net/Praveen16oct90/2bZAW/1095/

```
 div {
     width:200px;
     height:80px;
     background: red;
     top:150px;left:100px;
     position: relative;
     }

div:before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 40px; right: 0;
            border-right: 40px solid white;
             border-top: 40px solid red;
             width: 20;
      }
```

Comment: Hi, nice fiddle. But please see my need for flexible width :) Maybe with my sprite? http://i.imgur.com/z0UYpTX.png

Comment: Cant get u.. DO u want me to do it with ur image like this... if s send that png image... which u pasted above

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/u2ENb/ - if I use sprites, it's not repeating horizontally. (The small 1px thing).

Comment: This doesn't address the transparency/background image issue at all.